# How to update a nested property which type is generic from a immer produce function?

Tags: typescript, immer.js

I'd like to use `immer` in my react typescript application.

One of my reducer should deal with a state with a generic argument.

The generic argument can be anything (basic type, array, object, ...)

How to update such property within a produce method ?

Here's a [minimal repro code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&module=1#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-GGGy4AB5UkAKxw-T5VuYVrgAAUINprog4AAPAxaDAgUk0U4sVvtzvlcy++DhgaRpoAJil9VlUAMSBbcAAjAAGbsGAAsBDVCcFWv6OPHwz1YyEtfr5ullvYfkCtuhDvqzsJc+bBgAtABWNdLzfmH27uAswnCpg2wGgwxFUcZADccY33fJxxzRNk1TdNMxweIYKZIA):

```js
import { produce } from 'immer';

type SomeState<TResult> = {
    inner: TResult
}

type SetInner<TResult> = {
    type: 'SET_INNER';
    newValue: TResult;
}

const reducer = <TResult>(
    state: SomeState<TResult>,
    action: SetInner<TResult>
): SomeState<TResult> => {

    return produce(state, draft => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'SET_INNER':
                draft.inner = action.newValue;
                break;
        }
    });

}
```

This code fails on the line  `draft.inner = action.newValue;` with this error:

> Type 'TResult' is not assignable to type 'Draft'.

How to fix that ?

To clarify, I'd like these use cases to be possible:

```js
// Basic type
const initialState = {
    inner: "foo"
};

const action: SetInner<string> = {
    type: 'SET_INNER',
    newValue: "bar"
}

const newState = reducer(initialState, action);
console.log(newState);

// Object type
type Point = { x: number, y: number }
const initialState2 = {
    inner: { x: 10, y: 4 }
};

const action2: SetInner<Point> = {
    type: 'SET_INNER',
    newValue: { x: -5, y: 14 }
}

const newState2 = reducer(initialState2, action2);
console.log(newState2);
```

Comment: See [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8BGVm) example. `draft.inner` expects `newValue` to be wrapped into `Draft`. Made a change in `SetInner`. Let me know if it works for you. Btw, question is clear, not sure either why it was downvoted. Btw, happens with me all the time :D

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine: I get your point. I'll probably have to use `createDraft` function, because my actual object is the result of a 3rd party libray. Feel free to post your answer if you want the answer reward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider this example:

```js
import { produce, Draft } from 'immer';

type SomeState<TResult> = {
    inner: TResult
}

type SetInner<TResult> = {
    type: 'SET_INNER';
    newValue: Draft<TResult>; // <--------------- CHANGE IS HERE
}

const reducer = <TResult>(
    state: SomeState<TResult>,
    action: SetInner<TResult>
): SomeState<TResult> => {

    return produce(state, draft => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'SET_INNER': {

                draft.inner = action.newValue; // ok
                break;
            }


        }
    });

}

// Basic type
const initialState = {
    inner: "foo"
};

const action: SetInner<string> = {
    type: 'SET_INNER',
    newValue: "bar"
}

const newState = reducer(initialState, action);

console.log(newState);

// Object type
type Point = { x: number, y: number }
const initialState2 = {
    inner: { x: 10, y: 4 }
};

const action2: SetInner<Point> = {
    type: 'SET_INNER',
    newValue: { x: -5, y: 14 }
}

const newState2 = reducer(initialState2, action2);

console.log(newState2);
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NlLVXN)

I have wrapped `newValue` into [`Draft`](https://github.com/immerjs/immer/blob/master/src/types/types-external.ts#L36) type. According to source code, `Draft` states for:

```
/** Convert a readonly type into a mutable type, if possible */
type Draft<T>=...
```